# .NET Core 3.0 (Preview) - Visual Studio no recompila automáticamente las vistas Razor

Tags: visual-studio, razor, asp.net-core

Estuve probando con proyectos .Net CORE 2.2 y si modificaba algo en las vistas podía ver reflejado automáticamente los cambios sin tener que parar la ejecución ni recompilar. Sin embargo, pasé a la version .Net CORE 3.0 usando páginas razor y cuando cambio la vista y guardo tengo que parar la ejecución, compilar de nuevo y ejecutar para poder ver los cambios reflejados, ¿es normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comportamiento que describes es normal y se debe a que se ha llevado a cabo una limpieza del framework de ASP.NET Core para eliminar las dependencias con Roslyn (compilador de C# y VB.NET). Con este motivo se ha extraido la capacidad de recompilar las vistas y páginas Razor a un paquete nuget. En el siguiente enlace está la información más actualizada al respecto: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7647.

A partir de la Preview 3 de .NET Core 3 es posible incorporar la capacidad de recompilar Razor a nuestros proyectos de ASP.Net Core. Para ello debemos:

1. Añadir una referencia al paquete de Nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` ([paquete nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/)).
2. Actualizar el método `ConfigureServices` de nuestra applicación para que incluya una llamada al método `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` o `AddMvcRazorRuntimeCompilation`. El nombre del método depende de la versión de .NET Core 3 preview que estemos utilizando.

   En este ejemplo se muestra como invocar el método si estamos usando MVC:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   }
   ```

   y así sería para Razor pages:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome!!! Muchas gracias @Raúl Marín